# Divide LINQ to Entity queries in to different methods

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

want to be able to do something like this below. But I have a problem because the GetStudentByName method does not know what type data is.

Im able to  write the "data = data.Where(s => s.name == "Some name");" without any problems. But how do i divide it into different methods?

```
    private IQueryable GetStudents()
    {
        var data = from a in db.Anvandning
                   select a;
        return data;
    }
    public IQueryable GetStudentByName(string name) 
    {
        var data = GetStudents();

        data = data.Where(s => s.name == name);     <-- Error occurs
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IQueryable`, e.g

```
private IQueryable<Student> GetStudents()
{
    var data = from a in db.Anvandning
               select a;
    return data;
}

public IQueryable<Student> GetStudentByName(string name) 
{
    var data = GetStudents();

    data = data.Where(s => s.name == name);
    return data;
}
```

Note that these methods can be written more simply:

```
private IQueryable<Student> GetStudents()
{
    return db.Anvandning.Select(x => x);
}

public IQueryable<Student> GetStudentByName(string name) 
{
    return GetStudents().Where(s => s.name == name);
}
```